# Just use one variable

Tags: variables, tensorflow

Can I use Tensorflow in DNN by only use one "W" as my weight if I have 3 hidden layer?
I saw that other guys code use "W1","W2","W3" as their weight variables to compute forward propagation
I mean for the input layer to first hidden layer I use "W", and first hidden layer to second hidden layer I use "W", too, but I let my "W" become other dimension(like "W2") to compute.
Can I doing this?

Comment: You want to have two unique variables with the same name?

Comment: yes. because I want to compute forward propagation by a loop, not express then in one after one

Comment: Why not express all the weights in an array? Otherwise how do you expect to specify which unique weight vector you want to use for each propagation?

Comment: Thanks for your helping :D I will try to use array to express my weight. I'm just not sure if I just used "W", can I run optimizer?(the code can execute, but I'm not sure that correct)

Comment: How many layers do you have that you can't just express them separately?

Comment: I didn't use many layers(less than 5 layers) in my code. I can write them separately, but I want to express them in a loop, because I can adjust them easily(if I want to become 10 layers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily play with the size of the network (number of layers and neurons in them), you can do something like :

```
#input dimension
input_size = 10

#output dimension
output_size = 5

W = []

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, input_size])

# number of neurons in each layer
n_neurons = [input_size, 10, 7, output_size]

for i in xrange(0, len(n_neurons)-1):
    W.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_neurons[i],n_neurons[i+1]])))


def model():
    res = x
    #you don't need a relu in the last layer probably
    for i in xrange(0, len(n_neurons) - 2):
        res = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(res,W[i]))

    #thus this one is separate
    res = tf.matmul(res, W[-1])

    return res

out = model()
```

Just modify it depending on your application

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this method : D